# Setting val() from input text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need help with my function. I dont know how to set right text into val() function.
I have form, where I write text which I want to passing via val

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="formValueId" name="valueId"/>
    <input type="button" id="theButton" value="Send"/>
</form>
```

And here is the javascript:

```
var button = document.getElementById("theButton"),
value =  button.form.valueId.value;
button.onclick = function() {
    $("#modal").fadeOut(400, function() {
    $("#bg").fadeOut(400, function() {
      $theTarget.val("My inserted text should be here"); //Before here were (value)
    });
  });
}
```

It's continue of this - [jQuery selector - inserting value only to selected id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49175099/jquery-selector-inserting-value-only-to-selected-id/)
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set Value of Input Using Javascript Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700471/set-value-of-input-using-javascript-function)

Comment: What is `$theTarget` variable?

Comment: @Eddie   $theTarget = $(this);

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: I edit end of my question - I add link, where you can find function before adding input :)

Comment: What do you expect when the btn is clicked?

Comment: I have many INPUTS. When I click into input it will open this form in modal window. I write text into input, click submit. And wrote text will insert into clicked INPUT.

Comment: You can close this thread - After two hours of googling I found my answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5896287/jquery-passing-value-from-one-input-to-another

Comment: For others I changed only this row -           $theTarget.val($('#formValueId').val());